# Handle non numeric value in rest controller endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, error-handling, spring-restcontroller

When I call my API with non numeric value as % Spring reject the request with 400 http status code

```
 @RestController
 public Controller {
     @PostMapping
     public MyDto api(@RequestBody API request) {
     }
 }

 @Data
 public class API { 
       private Integer limit;
 }
```

For example sending:

```
POST http:\\localhost
Content-Type: application/json

 { "limit": "%%" }
```

How can I control the Exception and handle it in my code? for example make limit get null value instead of rejecting request? Must I change limit to String and convert it to Integer in code?

Comment: @Ranjan it isn't relevant to my question

Comment: Sorry, Instead of adding in another question. I added the comment here. Please Ignore.